# Memory Game in java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am trying to write a memory game. When we run app, "menu" appears first. The choices are one player and two player. When we click one player "level" selection part appears. Here choices are easy, medium, hard. Then one of them is clicked and game starts. But i am having trouble while implementing how to check selected cards equal or not. When a card is created, an id is assigned to it. And when two cards are clicked, I am checking ids. If ids are same, it returns "match", if it is not then "close" returns that means cards turn facedown. I am using MVC pattern. I have 9 classes. Card, Game, Level(enum), Menu, State(enum); views CardButton, GamePanel, LevelPanel, MenuPanel.
Class GamePanel:

```
package view;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import model.Game;
import model.State;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
private Game model;
ActionListener cardButtonActionListener;
private JFrame frame;

public GamePanel(Game gameModel, JFrame frame) {
    int width=gameModel.getRowSize();
    int height=gameModel.getColumnSize();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(width,height));

    this.model = gameModel;
    this.cardButtonActionListener = new CardButtonActionListener();
    this.frame = frame;
    show();
}

public void show() {
    for(int row=0; row<model.getRowSize(); row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<model.getColumnSize(); col++) {
            CardButton cardBtn = new CardButton(model.getCard(row, col));
            cardBtn.addActionListener(cardButtonActionListener);
            add(cardBtn);
        }
    }

    frame.repaint();
}

public class CardButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private int i = 0;
    CardButton b ,b2;
    State currentState;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(i==0){
            b = (CardButton) e.getSource();
            b.setFaceUp();
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("id "+b.getCard().getValue());
            i++;
        }
        else{
            b2 = (CardButton) e.getSource();
            b2.setFaceUp();
            i--;
        }


        currentState = model.compareCards(b, b2);

        if(currentState == State.Match){
            b.setVisible(false);
            b2.setVisible(false);               
        }

        if(currentState == State.Close){
            b.setFaceDown();
            b2.setFaceDown();               
        }

        if(currentState == State.Continue){

        }
    }

}
}
```

Class Game:

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import view.CardButton;


public class Game extends JPanel {

private Level level;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>> board;
private int rowSize;
private int colSize;
private ArrayList<Card> cardList;

public Game() {

}

public void setLevel(Level level,int x) {
    this.level = level;
    initBoard(x);
}

private void initBoard(int x) {
    // Create board according to level variable
    int s = x;
    rowSize = s;
    colSize = s;
    int a=rowSize*colSize/2;
    int b=0;
    this.board = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>>();
    for(int row=0; row<s; row++) {
        this.cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (int col=0; col<s/2; col++) {
            cardList.add(new Card(b));
            cardList.add(new Card(b));
            b++;
        }
        board.add(getCardList());
    }
    Collections.shuffle(board);
}

public ArrayList<Card> getCardList(){
    Collections.shuffle(cardList);
    return cardList;
}

public int getRowSize() {
    return rowSize;
}

public int getColumnSize() {
    return colSize;
}

public Card getCard(int row, int col) {
    return board.get(row).get(col);
}




public State compareCards(CardButton b, CardButton b2) {
    int v1, v2;
    v1 = b.getCard().getValue();
    v2 = b2.getCard().getValue();
    if(b.getCard()!= null && b2.getCard()!= null){
        return State.Continue;      
    }else{
        if(v1 == v2){
            return State.Match;
        }
        else{
            return State.Close;
            }
    }

}
}
```

GamePanel takes state info and decides card which position card should stay: faceup, facedown. But I couldn t implement action performed method(in GamePanel) and compareCards method(in Game) correctly. When I run code, I get null pointer exeption. Because I can not take 2 buttons info. One of them always stays null. I probably need to change this part:

```
if(i==0){
        b = (CardButton) e.getSource();
        b.setFaceUp();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("id "+b.getCard().getValue());
        i++;
    }
    else{
        b2 = (CardButton) e.getSource();
        b2.setFaceUp();
        i--;
    }
```

But I don t know how I can correct. Thank you.
Edit: Whole project is here http://cnv.as/21qoh

Comment: ... What is null, and where?

Comment: In class Game, "v2 = b2.getCard().getValue();" and in GamePanel, "currentState = model.compareCards(b, b2);"

Comment: You need to break this down into small, manageable tasks.

Comment: Maybe you should learn how to program bigger projects. Maybe a class diagram, a sequence diagram, ...

Comment: I didn't immediately start coding. I designed class diagram, interaction diagram and so on.. And I also code it without view, just console app. But when it comes to gui, I am having problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The b and b2 variables are null when the `CardButtonActionListener` is created.  So the first time `actionPerformed()` is called and you fall through your `if(i==0)` conditional statement, only one of b or b2 gets assigned the return value from e.getSource().  So when you call `currentState = model.compareCards(b, b2);` either b or b2 will still be null which as you found out will cause that method to throw a null pointer exception.

It looks like this isn't so much a coding error as it is that your design needs some additions.  The main reason is each card has its own instance of `CardButtonActionListener` and when clicked, this listener class isn't aware of any other cards that have already been clicked.  For a quick remedy to this you could add a `public static Card lastClicked;` member variable to your Game class (**disclaimer**: note I said '*quick*', not '*good*' as this violates good OOP design and in a multithreaded app would give you tons of trouble... but for a single threaded app like yours if you **just** want it to work this may be ok for you - but be warned that using public static variables like this is definitely **not** a good habit to get into).  Then you could modify your CardButtonActionListener.actionPerformed() like this (note that I did away with the 'i' variable):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    CardButton justClickedButton = e.getSource();
    justClickedButton.setFaceUp();
    CardButton previouslyClickedButton = Game.lastClicked;
    if(previouslyClickedButton == null){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("id "+justClickedButton.getCard().getValue());
        previouslyClickedButton = justClickedButton;
    }
    else{
         currentState = model.compareCards(justClickedButton, previouslyClickedButton);

         if(currentState == State.Match){
             justClickedButton.setVisible(false);
             previouslyClickedButton.setVisible(false);               
         }

         if(currentState == State.Close){
             justClickedButton.setFaceDown();
             previouslyClickedButton.setFaceDown();               
         }

         if(currentState == State.Continue){
         }

         previouslyClickedButton = null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is better than my "i" solution :)